# Importing updated PBI XML for TFS 2017 error element 'SystemControls' has invalid child element 'Control'. TF237070

Tags: tfs, customization, tfs-workitem, workitem

[image: desired layout]

TFS 2017 importing an updated XML for customizing PBI work item. Received error: The element 'SystemControls' has invalid child element 'Control'.
TF237070: Importing the definition failed. The definition you are trying to import did not validate against the schema. Edit the definition, then try to import it again.

This time seems to be different because of what I am trying to add in the "header" part of the work item that shows up no matter what tab you are on. We had state, reason, and iteration, and area. As you can tell by the control labels below I am trying to put some additional fields on the header that are constantly referenced

```
<SystemControls>
      <Control Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Title" EmptyText="&lt;Enter title here&gt;" />
      <Control Label="Assigned To" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Control Label="Lead BA:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.BAB.LeadBA" />
      <Control Label="State" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.State" />
      <Control Label="Status:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.BAB.Status" />
      <Control Label="Reason" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="System.Reason" ReadOnly="True" />
      <Control Label="Blocked Reason:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.BlockedReason" />
      <Control Label="Severity:" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity" />
      <Control Label="Area" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" FieldName="System.AreaPath" />
      <Control Label="Links" Type="LinksControl" Name="Links" />
      <Control Label="History" Type="WorkItemLogControl" FieldName="System.History" />
      <Control Label="Attachments" Type="AttachmentsControl" Name="Attachments" />
</SystemControls>
```

I will send a jpeg of the desired layout but in general I would like the header to be

> Title
>
> Assigned To

(these in the "shaded area" spaced across)

```
State                             Status                   Lead BA                     
Severity                          Area                     Blocked Reason
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify that section. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops#header-customization).

> For TFS 2017, On-premises XML process model: You can modify select elements within the SystemControls section, such as changing the EmptyText attribute value for the System.Title field. In general, we recommend you don't customize this section much more than that. **For example, you can't remove fields from or add other fields within this section.**

Comment: Thank you. Now do you know if I can change the icons to actually say the word instead of having a paperlink and chain link and "circle"?

Comment: No, you can't. You cannot modify system fields.

Comment: Ok, ty, last question, in the set "header" section referencing my original request. I understand now that we don't modify the systemcontrols section, but for the layout that is system provided for state, reason, area, iteration... My question is how does the code tell it to each go on the first or second line/row. I don't want to change it, I'm just curious b/c below for the other areas of the work item I have in my code <group>